# Best practices to clone/create an image for the existing linux system

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart

I recently had a CentOS6.9 system and I installed quite a lot of applications (from yum and also source code like specific python version). Now I need to do the same for multiple devices. Is there any best way to do that?

I researched a bit and found out I can make a kickstart image. However, the tutorial I followed does not include the way to include the application I installed from source code. Should I use the kickstart image for my case or is there other way to clone the existing SSD to a new drive?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The main reasons to develop a kickstart solution are willing to be able to repeat multiple time the same installation and also having the possibility to develop your setup in the future. 
A bullet proof kickstart solution will take time to develop and debug.

Also, if one of those points is not in the direction you want, cloning the disk is the easiest and quickest solution. 
Usually, people do this using [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep multiple systems in sync, you're probably better off using a configuration management tool such as [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [SaltStack](https://saltstack.com/), [CFEngine](https://cfengine.com/), etc.

The problem with the kickstart or clone approach is that they only apply at the time that the system or device is created.  That means that if you decide later that you need to have a new application installed on all of the systems or devices that already exist, you will need to do so manually, one-by-one.

Comment: It's also worth noting that provisioning vs a reused cache (which can be compressed in an archive easily with apt-get) during installation of packages is not an expensive process. Further, both Fedora/RHEL/CentOS and Ubuntu provide fairly good remote installation and configuration and Debian has configurable net install at least.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what you're talking about or how it's relevant to my answer, @jdwolf.